# AngularJS making routes insensitive?

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I know that in Backbone.js I can use a regex like this

```
_routeToRegExp: function (route) {
    route = route.replace(this.escapeRegExp, "\\$&")
           .replace(this.namedParam, "([^\/]*)")
           .replace(this.splatParam, "(.*?)");

    return new RegExp('^' + route + '$', 'i'); // Just add the 'i'
}
```

To make routes insensitive aka `/product` is the same as `/Product` is the same as `/PRODUCT`

I am having an issue though trying to figure out how to do the same in Angular.js though, what is the sanest way to do this inside the application instead of using a blanket approach such as htaccess rewriting? Thanks

Comment: Why not just add `(?i)` to the beginning of each regex? Wait, there is nothing in your regex that forces sensitivity, right?

Comment: @Sin I'm asking about Angular, not backbone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/newEvent',
        {
            templateUrl: 'templates/NewEvent.html',
            controller: 'EditEventController',
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true
        });
```

Where caseInsensitiveMatch: true means that /product == /Product;
caseInsensitiveMatch: false means that /product <> /Product

Comment: Depends which version you're using

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing). It's much more advanced than Angular's built in router and lets you define regular expressions. It also lets you define sub-views, etc. There's also a built in redirect feature so you can do something like psuedocode: `$urlRouterProvider.when(anything, convertolowercase);` for a global approach, although I have not tested it, it also supports regex.